# XQuery: why does this transform modify the source document?

Tags: xml, xquery, xquery-update

I'm working with this very simple XML doc (that I borrowed from a tutorial), books-mod.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<bookstore>

<book category="COOKING">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>

<book category="CHILDREN">
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>

<book category="WEB">
  <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
  <author>James McGovern</author>
  <author>Per Bothner</author>
  <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
  <author>James Linn</author>
  <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>49.99</price>
</book>

<book category="WEB">
  <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
  <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

And using this query:

```
copy $d := doc("books-mod.xml")
modify (
  for $t in $d//title
  return replace value of node $t with concat($t, " in bed")
)
return $d
```

This query runs and does what I expect (i.e. appends the text " in bed" to each book title).  However, surprisingly, it also modifies the source document... I thought the whole point of `copy` with this transform was that we modify a *copy* of the document.

What am I missing here?

I'm using `xqilla` with `-u` to execute the query.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, this is definitely a bug. The *Transform Expression* is explicitly [*not* an updating expression](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-update-10/#id-transform):

> A transform expression is a simple expression because it does not modify the value of any existing nodes.

Which version of XQilla are you using? The [change log for version 2.2.2](http://sourceforge.net/news/?group_id=152021&id=277000) mentions something related:

> - Fixed the transform expression to copy document nodes rather than dissolving them.

So probably it's already fixed.

Comment: Hmm. I'm using 2.3.0 so it ought to be there... +1 for confirming this behavior is wrong. I'll have to dig around and see if this is the one I'm seeing.

Comment: Actually, the effect of a query on persistent filestore is entirely implementation-defined; a query processor that formatted your disk when you wrote 2+2 might be unpopular, but it would not be non-conformant.

Comment: I didn't realize that, bot now that I think of it, it makes perfect sense. The more you know...